# Как передать массив данных из компонента в сервис ? reactjs

Tags: reactjs

В общем осуществлял поиск (фильтрую массив, в котором хранятся все данные и отфильтрованные данные заношу в новый), поиск работает корректно, но до этого делал еще пагинацию и она работает от старого массива данных, в котором хранятся все данные, в итоге пагинация живет своей жизнью. Я понимаю так, что надо просто заменить старый массив на новый, но не знаю как передать его правильно. Количество страниц я определяю по длине массива в отдельном сервисе, который в последствии импортируется в компонент с пагинацией.

```
 import { products } from '../data';


const service = {
    getData: ({from, to}) =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

            const data = products.slice(from, to);

            resolve({
                count: products.length,
                data: data
            })
        });
    }
}

export default service;
```

выше, то как я из обычного json забираю данные, реализовано не в компоненте, потом просто count используется для определения страниц. Думаю сюда как-то импортировать массив с отфильтрованными данными, но никак не получается.